# "Unused import os from wildcard import"

Tags: python, audio, mp3, mp4, moviepy

I'm trying to do this code, but when I  want to run it, the Visual code shows me this "Unused import os from wildcard import". The problem is at the time of import moviepy however I don't know how to fix It.
I would appreciate if someone can help me.

-this is the code:

---

```
from moviepy.editor import *

mp4_file = r'C:\Users\s\OneDrive\Documentos\Python\cancion.mp4'

mp3_file = r'C:\Users\s\OneDrive\Documentos\Python\cancion.mp3'

videoclip = VideoFileClip(mp4_file)

audioclip = videoclip.audio

audioclip.write_audiofile(mp3_file)

audioclip.close()

videoclip.close()
```

Comment: If it’s just a warning, ignore it. Sounds like a minor issue from within moviepy.

Comment: Could you use `from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip`?

Comment: Yes, but after running the code, it said "KeyError: 'video_fps". I search for it and happened because the video I want to turn it to mp3( the mp4 video) is just audio and doesn't have images. I don't know what should I do